# How to create copy of one column in same table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with one columns of integer data type. I want to add another columns with string data type.

Finally I want to copy the values in first column to the second columns.
That means I want to copy the integer data from column one and copy that to second column in string format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting the column to a `CHAR` will do what you want:

```
UPDATE `table` SET column2 = CAST(column1 AS CHAR)
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions when they don't say what they've tried.  Otherwise, you're just doing their homework for them.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to add columns. Syntax for adding is

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD column_name datatype;
```

To transfer:

```
UPDATE tablename SET second_column = CAST(first_column AS CHAR);
```